# Linux: Quiet mode and how to make command wait to finish before next

Tags: linux, unix, yum

If i do a command like say

```
yum install -y -q packageX
```

How do i ensure that it waits for finish before doing the next command?

My goal is to have as little unnecessary output as possible but to do each command sequentially with each completing

Answer (score 1):

**Linux commands are generally already silent** unless there is a problem, that way you only have to pay attention if paying attention is required. Some commands have options to silence their useful and non-problematic output, use `man COMMAND_NAME` for that or check out TL;DR pages here which are like `man` but beginner friendly: https://tldr.sh/

For your specific case here you're already using the silenced version of `yum` as you've passed it the `-q` flag. The man docs for yum, `man yum` or online (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/yum.8.html) state that `-q`

```
-q, --quiet
          Run without output.
```

**As for the commands:**

Use `&&` to chain commands where the success (specifically if the command returns `0` which is often attributed to success) of the previous command is required for the next to be executed.

Here's an example:

`cd ./foo && ls`

This translates as: attempt to change directory into the folder `foo` in the current directory, if-and-only-if that succeeds (returns 0) run `ls`. If `foo` doesn't exist or it otherwise cannot change directory into `foo` then `ls` will not run.

In your case if you wanted to run a command only if that package of yours successfully installed you would do the following where `ls` is a command that is perhaps more interesting in this case.

`yum install -y -q packageX && ls`

Just for completeness as conversations about `&&` often bring about `;`, if you don't care whether the last command completes successfully (returns 0) and just want to chain commands use `;` instead.

`cd ./foo; ls`

Now even if `cd ./foo` fails the `ls` will still execute.

Comment: For completeness you can add also few words about `cd ./foo || ls` :)